# How to replace all form input fields

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to replace all form input field with their respective value and underline them as well as but when I select on dropdown only the first value appears even if I select third or second. Here's what I have tried:

```js
jQuery('.btn-print').click(function() {

  jQuery(".form1").find(':input').each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).val() && jQuery(this).attr('type') !== 'hidden') {

      jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).replaceWith('<u>' + jQuery(this).val() + '</u>'));
    } else if (jQuery(this).val() === '') {
      jQuery(this).replaceWith('________');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form1">
  <input type="text" value="ABC" />
  <input type="text" value="DEF" />
  <select name="acces_specfi" class="selectpicker" data-size="10" data-style="btn-info">
    <option value="public">public</option>
    <option value="public">private</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" class="btn-print" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: I tried it and it is working, check it here http://jsfiddle.net/zmj9n9km/

Comment: What do you mean by select dropdown?? Your jquery code just find the input field..

Comment: i have update my question its bootstrap select which is not working

Comment: opps actually my value is same for both i see thanks guys